# Unity3D Texture2D.Resize leads to Error: afterDecrement >= 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error, texture2d

I have a `Texture2D` that can be created and resized, and also destroyed quickly depending on user key input.

If I quickly hit keys to destroy/create the texture I sometimes get errors, obviously caused by the texture:

```
afterDecrement >= 0
UnityEngine.Texture2D:Resize(Int32, Int32)
```

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix this?

Comment: That sort of message is usually a failed assertion in the Unity internals. In this case, it looks like a texture is complaining that its width or height is 0. Depending on what you're doing, this might mean that you're resizing a deleted texture, or resizing an existing texture with bad parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the info rutter! I guess in Unity one generally should not dispose objects and let Destroy(gameObject) take care of it all? I have a feeling that trying to dispose child objects, grahpics etc. manually will lead to errors like these. I'm a bit memory-leak paranoid, excuse me!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! There was indeed a condition in my view invalidation method where the width set for the texture was 0 and in the next frame set to a proper width. I've added a check and the exception doesn't appear anymore.